# Why Redis considered to be CP?

Tags: database, redis

In short the [brewer's CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) states that any database is either CA,CP or AP

Why do people consider Redis as a CP database?

Comment: Can you point us to the source of the claim that it's considered as CP?

Comment: Sure -> http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.posterous.com/nahurst/IAHBjwAxcmieJzvtqqyIgriyIzqquwwxumguABujzlzHEbEeJgvhCFcriika/media_httpfarm5static_mevIk.png.scaled1000.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFZAE65UYRT34AOQ&Expires=1312272549&Signature=%2Bn2yiDOv8CCKVJbphSwdxVQVWlk%3D

Comment: It's giving me access denied :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@seppoo0010 is correct.  It is more meaningful to speak of a Redis node in terms of Atomicity, Durability, etc.

Also note that [CAP is a somewhat problematic paradigm](https://twitter.com/#!/eric_brewer/status/26819094612).  I second Dr. Brewer's recommendation of [Coda Hale's informative rant](http://codahale.com/you-cant-sacrifice-partition-tolerance). (See also [comments by Daniel Abdi](http://dbmsmusings.blogspot.com/2010/04/problems-with-cap-and-yahoos-little.html)). Also note [Jeff Darcy](http://pl.atyp.us/wordpress/?p=2521/) and [Dan Weinreb's comments](http://danweinreb.org/blog/category/software-engineering).

[Stonebraker disagrees](http://voltdb.com/company/blog/clarifications-cap-theorem-and-data-related-errors).

[Edit: Dan Weinreb's deep digging of CAP really is quite excellent.  Highly recommended]

Finally, here is ["the proof" of CAP](http://people.csail.mit.edu/sethg/pubs/BrewersConjecture-SigAct.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

The CAP Theorem refers to distributed computer systems.

Since Redis is not per se distributed (clustering is under development) being CP/CA/PA depends on the clustering implementation.

Comment: Can u explain in short how to implement CP distributed reids?

Comment: Not really. If interested, read http://www.aosabook.org/en/nosql.html specially 13.4 and 13.5.